# Sort Strings numerical

Tags: python, string, sorting, numeric

I analysing Breast Cancer Data Set (archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer)

Here is `df.head()`

```
             Class           age    menopause   tumor-size  inv-nodes   node-caps   deg-malig   breast  breast-quad irradiat
0   no-recurrence-events    40-49    premeno      20-24       0-2         no            2        right     right_up   no
1   no-recurrence-events    40-49    premeno      20-24       0-2         no            2        left      left_low   no
2   no-recurrence-events    60-69    ge40         15-19       0-2         no            2        right     left_up    no
3   no-recurrence-events    40-49    premeno       0-4        0-2         no            2        right     right_low  no
4   no-recurrence-events    60-69    ge40         15-19       0-2         no            2        left      left_low   no
```

Now dataframe is string.
I wanna change df for example:
col class:

```
no-recurrence-events to 0
recurrence-events to 1
```

col age:

```
20-29 - 0
30-39 - 1
40-49 - 2
```

**All strings IN NEW DF must be sorted.**
How can i do this?

What i do:

```
list_of_columns = headerList
df[list_of_columns] = df[list_of_columns].apply(lambda col:pd.Categorical(col).codes)
df
```

output:

```
Class   age menopause   tumor-size  inv-nodes   node-caps   deg-malig   breast
  0      0      2          6           0           1           1        1  
  0      1      2          5           5           2           1        1
  0      1      2          1           0           1           0        0
```

But now the 0 in my df is not the first sorted data.
I think now i explained better.

Comment: df = df.sort_values(by=['age'], ascending=False)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea but its still string. I want to sort by descdending and code this to 0,1,2,3,4,5 by sorted group age

Comment: Ok. Lets start again. I analysing Breast Cancer Data Set (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer) the age column is grouped like this: 50-59.. etc. I wanna sort column Age and code it from 0 to 6. The zero is 20-29 group, the 1 is 30-39 etc. I do coding age, but its not sorted good. Now in 0 is 40-49 like you see on link photo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted()` to [sort a list](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics).

And then you can just create a dictionary with your encoding rules, in this case just the order in which the items are sorted.

```
sorted_age = sorted(df.age.unique())
age_encoding = {sorted_age[i]:i for i in range(len(sorted_age))}

df['age'] = df['age'].map(age_encoding)
```

If you want to map different encodings to different columns, you could arrange the encodings in a list or a dictionary mapping column to encoding and then loop over the columns, but you can also use pandas' [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace({'age': age_encoding, 'Class': class_encoding, 'menopause' : menopause_encoding})
# each foo_encoding is a dictionary like the one in the previous example.
```

Comment: I update my post. Sorry for problems.

Comment: How to do that to all columns?
I know, i must use for loop.

Comment: @dankie Yes, you can use a loop, but I added one more option to my answer to account for many columns using pandas' tools.